# Having trouble calling videos from array

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working on a branching video application and I'm having trouble with code in the branching area. Here's a snippet from the AddMyListener function...

```
    function myAddListener() {
  if (new Date() - startTime > (60 * 60 * 1000)) {
    return; 
  }
  if (currentIndex == 0) {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoSources.length;
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
  }
  if (currentIndex == 1 && eX == true) {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoSources.length;
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
    console.log(currentIndex);
  }  
  if (currentIndex == 1 && eX == false){
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 2) % videoSources.length;
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
    console.log(currentIndex);
  }
  if (currentIndex == 3){
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % videoSources.length;
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
    console.log(currentIndex);
  }
  if (currentIndex == 4){
    currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % videoSources.length;
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    myVideo.src = videoSources[currentIndex];
    myVideo.addEventListener('ended', myNewSrc, false);
    console.log(currentIndex);
  }
}
```

From CurrentIndex 0=>1 everything is fine. However, if we ran the "false" function, instead of going +2, playing the appropriate video, then continuing -- it would go +2,+1,+1 essentially skipping through.

Can anyone please chime in?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `switch` statement rather then having multiple `ifs` this would help you in skipping through as well. 
You can cases like

you can put `index` numbers in `cases` like `case: 1` etc. 
and then add an if condition inside the case for handling `ex === true / false` so It would be something like this

```
switch(index) {
case 1: 
    if(ex === true) {
        // Do something
    } else if(ex === false) {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```